# RSYSLOG force only TLS 1.3 version

Tags: linux, ssl, rsyslog, gnutls

Debian: 10.10
rsyslog-gnutls: 8.1901.0-1
libgnutls: 30.6.7

I search in where **path and name file** insert this var "gnutlsPriorityString".

What is her path? And her Name file? to put this var "gnutlsPriorityString"?

My goal is the TLS only work with "TLS1.3" and I test with rsyslog client.

References links:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/962207/option-to-configure-tls-version-in-rsyslog
- [https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Application_002dspecific-priority-strings.html#:~:text=The%20priority%20strings%20can%20be,%2DPRIORITY%3A%2BSRP%20%27](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Application_002dspecific-priority-strings.html#:%7E:text=The%20priority%20strings%20can%20be,%2DPRIORITY%3A%2BSRP%20%27)).
- https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Overriding-the-default-priority-string.html
- https://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Priority-Strings.html
- https://serverfault.com/questions/986490/rsyslog-with-custom-tls-connection
- https://github.com/mozilla/server-side-tls/issues/30

Comment: Hi! You seem to have forgotten to ask a question that we can answer.

Comment: Hi! I search in where path and name file insert this var "gnutlsPriorityString".

Comment: a) I must admit I don't understand the sentence, b) that sentence is not a question, could you make a sentence that ends in "?"?

Comment: Hi again, I putted three questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found:

For Rsyslog 8.0 you need to put this `gnutlsprioritystring="SECURE128:-VERS-TLS-ALL:+VERS-TLS1.3`         when you load the `icmp` module, example:

```
module(load="imtcp"
        StreamDriver.mode="1"
        StreamDriver.authmode="anon"
        gnutlsprioritystring="SECURE128:-VERS-TLS-ALL:+VERS-TLS1.3"
)
```

Good Debug ;)